# in Ember, Can I (de)serialize 3 level Nested JSON with DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

My server returns JSON like below and I cannot change it into sideloading style.

```
{
  "owner": {
    "id": 293,
    "servers": [{
      "id": 32,
      "hostname": "host1",
      "networks": [ {
        "id": 1234,
        "ip": 10.10.10.10
      }, {
        "id": 5678,
        "ip": 10.10.20.10
      }]
    }, {
      "id": 33,
      "hostname": "host2",
      "networks": [ {
        "id": 1234,
        "ip": 10.10.10.11
      }, {
        "id": 5678,
        "ip": 10.10.20.11
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

There is one and only API endpoint for serving above single JSON, and for it, I written three models - owner, server, network - setup like below:

network:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({
  servers: DS.hasMany('server'),
});
```

server:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({
  hostname: DS.attr('string'),
  owner: DS.belongsTo('owner', {async: true}),
  networks: DS.hasMany('network', {async: true}),
});
```

owner:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({
  servers: DS.hasMany('server', {async: true}),
});
```

Serializer for owner and server like this:

```
import TestSerializer from './test';
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default TestSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    servers: { embedded: 'always' },
  }
});

import TestSerializer from './test';
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default TestSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    networks: { embedded: 'always' },
  } 
});
```

when I run it without network-server relation, server-owner relation solved by serializer and it is find. but with 3 level relation, it fails with very long error:

> EmberError@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:27348:15
>   _emberMetalCore.default.assert@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16067:13
>   ember$data$lib$system$store$serializer$response$$_normalizeSerializerPayloadItem/http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:76803:17
>   ember$data$lib$system$store$serializer$response$$_normalizeSerializerPayloadItem/http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:76815:35
>   ember$data$lib$system$store$serializer$response$$_normalizeSerializerPayloadItem/<@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:76791:12
>   .eachRelationship/<@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:87742:11
>   Map.prototype.forEach/cb@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:29106:11
>   OrderedSet.prototype.forEach@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:28889:11
>   Map.prototype.forEach@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:29110:7
>   .eachRelationship@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:87741:9
>   ember$data$lib$system$store$serializer$response$$_normalizeSerializerPayloadItem@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:76785:7
>   ember$data$lib$system$store$serializer$response$$_normalizeSerializerPayload@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:76753:18
>   ember$data$lib$system$store$$Store<.push@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:84416:18
>   ember$data$lib$serializers$embedded$records$mixin$$EmbeddedRecordsMixin<._extractEmbeddedHasMany/<@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:86708:11
>   ember$data$lib$serializers$embedded$records$mixin$$EmbeddedRecordsMixin<._extractEmbeddedHasMany@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:86706:9 ember$data$lib$serializers$embedded$records$mixin$$EmbeddedRecordsMixin<._extractEmbeddedRecords/<@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:86671:17
>   .eachRelationship/<@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:87742:11
>   Map.prototype.forEach/cb@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:29106:11
>   OrderedSet.prototype.forEach@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:28889:11
>   Map.prototype.forEach@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:29110:7
>   .eachRelationship@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:87741:9
>   ember$data$lib$serializers$embedded$records$mixin$$EmbeddedRecordsMixin<._extractEmbeddedRecords@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:86664:1 ember$data$lib$serializers$embedded$records$mixin$$EmbeddedRecordsMixin<.normalize@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:86399:16
>   apply@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:34198:1
>   superWrapper@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:33836:15
>   ember$data$lib$serializers$rest$serializer$$RESTSerializer<.extractArray/normalizedArray<@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:77580:20
>   ember$data$lib$serializers$rest$serializer$$RESTSerializer<.extractArray@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:77579:33
>   ember$data$lib$serializers$json$serializer$$JSONSerializer<.extractFindAll@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:74872:16
>   ember$data$lib$serializers$json$serializer$$JSONSerializer<.extract@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:74856:16
>   ember$data$lib$system$store$serializer$response$$normalizeResponseHelper@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:76729:33
>   ember$data$lib$system$store$finders$$_findAll/http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:79011:25
>   Backburner.prototype.run@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:10843:18
>   ember$data$lib$system$store$$Store<._adapterRun@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:84741:16
>   ember$data$lib$system$store$finders$$_findAll/<@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:79010:9
>   tryCatch@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:67710:14
>   invokeCallback@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:67725:15
>   publish@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:67693:9
>   @http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:44051:7
>   Queue.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:11571:9
>   Queue.prototype.flush@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:11635:11
>   DeferredActionQueues.prototype.flush@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:11436:11
>   Backburner.prototype.end@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:10725:9
>   Backburner.prototype.run@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:10847:13
>   run@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:31688:12
>   ember$data$lib$adapters$rest$adapter$$RestAdapter<.ajax/http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:72892:15
>   jQuery.Callbacks/fire@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:3346:10
>   jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:3458:7
>   done@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:9512:5
>   .send/callback@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:9916:8 
>   vendor.js:44090:9

So, Can I use EmbeddedRecordsMixin for it? or how can I get right result on this condition?